# Show a popup when a dropdown value is selected with only js

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want a simple js script to show a popup when a specific option from the dropdown is selected. The name of the selection tag is "ProfileType[0]"

It does not have a id attribute and it contains those special character. I tried to use jquery but no luck with it. And i would prefer if the selection tag code will be untouched means without adding any onchange event to it. And one more thing it already have a onchange event. I know its possible with jquery. You have any good code for this.

```
<select name="ProfileType[0]" onchange="window.location.href = "join.php?pid=" + this.value;">
<option value="1">Personal</option>
<option value="2">Professor</option>
<option value="4">Student</option>
</select>
```

Any help will be very much appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify the question a smidge? What will load in the pop up window?

Comment: this might help, written for your case specifically: http://jsfiddle.net/BgGTH/5/ cheers,

Comment: thanks but i can't use ids...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="ProfileType\\[0\\]"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
            alert("Your popup here");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YVNMK/

You don't say which option is the specific one you care about, so I've gone with the first one.

Note that attaching the handler with jQuery should not affect the inline `onchange`, though your existing `onchange` is invalid because you've tried to use double-quotes inside other double-quotes - change one or other set of doubles to single-quotes:

```
onchange="window.location.href='join.php?pid=' + this.value;"
```

Comment: the demo link you posted is not working. maybe something is wrong in this code

Comment: Why are you escaping the square bracket using a double slash. Isn't one enought?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not working", but the demo link I posted works fine for me (I wouldn't have posted it otherwise). You said in a comment under another answer that no jQuery works: in your own code are you including jquery.js before your other script(s)?

Comment: @Starx - If you want a JS string literal to contain a backslash you have to escape it with another backslash. The resulting backslash then escapes the square bracket for jQuery's sake (that part has nothing to do with JS syntax).

Comment: Above Code will work correctly. It will not show a Popup when the page is loaded but it will show popup when the selection is changed.

Comment: yes it has a jquery.js file and it has other jquery code also. But in my case i am trying everything and no popup comes up. Do you think its because the reload of the page because of onchange event in it. Sorry for being a pain but i am not good at jquery or js. I mostly do php stuff.

Comment: Try temporarily removing the inline `onchange` at least until you get the extra popup functionality working.

Comment: yup removed that onchange but still the same problem. And i am including it in the head. Is it okay?

Comment: It's fine to include it in the head as long as you have it in a document ready as in my answer. (Otherwise you need to include it after the select element.)

Comment: hahaha :) :) :) funny
I copied it from http://jsfiddle.net/YVNMK/ source code and its working now.. lol

Comment: I will try to find the reason but so many thanks to you and everybody who tried to help...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select[name='ProfileType[0]']").change(function (){
   if($(this).val() == 1){ // Check if the selected value is 1
    // Create the popup
   };
});
```

I hope this point you in the right direction

Comment: Ok, maybe its a complete diffrent question. Couse both examples are valid

Comment: go here http://jsfiddle.net/YVNMK/ and check its not working something is wrong in the code

Comment: @Prashank - that link works fine for me. When you select an item in the drop-down the page tries to navigate to the url specified in the inline `onchange` - which doesn't work because it doesn't have the right path, but that part is _your_ code (except I fixed the quotes) which you said you wanted to leave as is. Meanwhile, if you happen to select the first item it also displays the `alert()`.